# GroupingBy in Java8-Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I am using Grouping-By in Streams:

1: I want to know how can i use "Grouping-By" twice in Collect method.

2: Secondly,What is the strategy to define **return types** in grouping?

1:

```
Map<String,String> sum1 = Items.items().stream()
                       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Items::getName,
                               Collectors.groupingBy(Items::getName)));
```

error message:

> 1:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - incompatible types: inference variable D has
>   incompatible equality constraints java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer
>   at collectorsinjava.CollectorsInJava.main(CollectorsInJava.java:33)

2:

```
     Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> sum1 = Items.items().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Items::getName,
                            Collectors.groupingBy(Items::getQuantity)));
```

error message:

> 2:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - incompatible types: inference variable K has
>   incompatible bounds equality constraints: java.lang.String lower
>   bounds: java.lang.Integer at
>   collectorsinjava.CollectorsInJava.main(CollectorsInJava.java:37)

This is my list of items:

```
List<Items> item = Arrays.asList(new Items("A",22,new BigDecimal("23.3")),
 new Items("B",33,new BigDecimal("19.99")),

 new Items("C",31,new BigDecimal("23.3")),

 new Items("D",22,new BigDecimal("19.99")),

 new Items("B",33,new BigDecimal("23.3")),

 new Items("C",31,new BigDecimal("19.99")),

 new Items("D",22,new BigDecimal("23.3"))
);
```

can someone please suggest how I can avoid the compilation errors?

Comment: What is the desired output in these two snippets? And why are you grouping twice by the same property in the first snippet?

Comment: @Eran i want to use GroupingBy twice ,what is the correct way to define types in collect method?

Comment: @Aominè the second condition is till not working with your strategy.

Comment: @BeenishSajjad as is, your code doesn't compile. are you trying to remove the compilation errors? if yes then post the error message. when you chain grouping collectors, you'll get back a _multi-level_ map hence my suggestion above and it should work when used properly.

Comment: @Aominè Yup i am getting error because i have used incorrect data types in Map and again whats the way to define return types in  multi-level map?

Comment: @Aominè Can you please explain what are the rules for defining receiver type in Collectors?

Comment: @Aomine Thanks alot.

Comment: @BeenishSajjad cool, no probs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group twice or however many times you want by chaining *groupingBy* collectors as you've done but the issue here is that the receiver type is incorrect.

the receiver type for the first query should be:

```
Map<String, List<Items>> resultSet = Items.items().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Items::getName));
```

as there is no need to group by the same property twice.

when you have two or more grouping collectors chained together, you'll receive a *multi-level* map so therefore the receiver type for the second query should be:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Items>>> anotherResultSet
```

Otherwise, if you want to adapt a Collector to perform an additional finishing transformation then you're looking for a [collectingAndThen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-).

Comment: Can you please explain what are the rules for defining receiver type in Collectors?

Comment: @BeenishSajjad have a looking at this tutorial  --> [Guide to Java 8 groupingBy Collector](http://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector) & [Java 8 Grouping with Collectors | groupingBy method tutorial with examples](https://www.javabrahman.com/java-8/java-8-grouping-with-collectors-groupingby-method-tutorial-with-examples/)